# jQuery: Replacing an Array with Another

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I use the below code for replacing all instances of a character with another:

```
$("#myContent").each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace("1", "一"));
})

$("#myContent").each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace("2", "二"));
})

$("#myContent").each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace("3", "三"));
})

...
```

How can I put all these together, something like replacing an array with another?

Comment: Why are you using `each` for  one selected element?

Comment: first of all looks like you have multple elements with same ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, untested:

```
var replacers = {
    '一': /1/gi,
    '二': /2/gi,
    '三': /3/gi
};

var el = $("#myContent"),
    html = el.html();

for (var key in replacers) {
    html = html.replace(replacers[key], key);
}
el.html(html);
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not change every instance of the character. For example, in "2011," only the first "1" will change.

Comment: Updated the post. Note that if you're doing this a lot you should probably cache the regexes.

Comment: My array only consists of numbers, so basically it has ten members. Is caching still required? In any case, please tell me how should I cache them.

Comment: In that case I would just create the regexp up front, updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, instead :

```
var html = $(this).html();

html = html.replace(/1/g, "一");
html = html.replace(/2/g, "二");
html = html.replace(/3/g, "三");

$(this).html(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var replacers = {
    '1': '一',
    '2': '二',
    '3': '三'
};

$("#myContent").html(function(index, html){
    $.each(replacers, function(i, v){
        html = html.replace(new RegExp(i, 'g'), v, 'g')
    })
    return html;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NYdY4/1/)

Comment: This won't change every instance of the character. For example, in "2011," only the first "1" will change.